# Visual Studio Serial Command timer

Tags: timer, serial-port

I am new to Visual studio I am looking to create a program that would time the time it takes to send a serial command to one camera and recieve an output from a second camera.

I am thinking

Start timer <>
Send Serial command to IP address 192.168.188.2 tcp port 2001 * I this is my biggest challange to call and send the <> serial command to this address
look for output from camera 2 IP Address 192.168.188.3 tcp port 2001
stop timer

I have no idea what I am doing and dont know where to even look for syntax

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? Can you create and read/write from a socket? We have no idea of what your level of expertise is. We need more info.